# how do I make this repeat so many times

Tags: powershell

how would I make this repeat so many time example like 2 times I understand how to make a powershell command repeat but not a powershell script

```
webHookUrl = 'discord webhook'
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$embedArray = @()
$title       = ''
$description = 'pov bean'
$color       = '255'
#ignore this its just a bean
$imageUrl = 'https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/922271992890142781/929942952501981265/9ca3a0b4352ca3ff74b89cb208ceda6ab5-kidney-bean.png?width=1005&height=670' 
$imageObject = [PSCustomObject]@{
    url = $imageUrl
}
$embedObject = [PSCustomObject]@{
    title       = $title
    description = $description
    color       = $color
    thumbnail   = $imageObject
}
$embedArray.Add($embedObject) | Out-Null
$payload = [PSCustomObject]@{
    embeds = $embedArray
}
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $webHookUrl -Body ($payload | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 4) -Method Post -ContentType 'application/json'
```

did

```
For ($i = 0; $i -lt 5; $i++) {
    Write-Output $i
}
```

the 5 is the amount i want it to repeat and well that worked

Comment: `1..2 |ForEach-Object { .\path\to\script.ps1 }`

Comment: `do { } until( )` or `do { } while ( )` or `while ( ) { }`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen how exactly would i get it to repeat 5 times and not just repeat forever

Comment: `1..2` expands to an array of two items, so it'll only happen twice. `1..5` for 5 times

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen either i did something wrong or im not doing it right i mean it work but it does not stop after 5 times so either i place it in the wrong spot or like i said i did something wrong

Comment: What's the name of the script?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen discordwebhookmessagesender

Comment: You need to rename it to have a `.ps1` extension (eg. `discordwebhookmessagesender.ps1`) - are you sure it runs _at all_?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen my bad it does have a .ps1 extension

Comment: and yes it runs

Comment: And it runs forever when you do `1..5 |ForEach-Object { .\discordwebhookmessagesender }`? I'm afraid I'm at a loss :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen ok i found out what i did wrong now it works but voids everything else? it wont send the message it will send it once then somehow void the rest im a bit confused the error im getting is `.discordwebhookmessagesender.ps1 : The term '.discordwebhookmessagesender.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable 
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.`

Comment: `.\discordwebhookmessagesender.ps1`, not `.discordwebhookmessagesender.ps1`, you're missing a backslash

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen my mistake completely forgot to do that now it still has the problem where it sends the message once

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen got it to work by doing ```For ($i = 0; $i -lt 5; $i++) {
    Write-Output $i
}```

Comment: `foreach ($i in 1..10) { $i }`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to loop my powershell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25870201/how-to-loop-my-powershell-script)

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to make a powershell script repeat, maybe this might help [how to loop my powershell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25870201/how-to-loop-my-powershell-script?rq=1)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).